# Is it safe to add additional 127.0.0.1 entries to /etc/hosts?

Tags: mac-osx, localhost, hosts-file

I want to add this entry:

```
127.0.0.1       api.localhost
```

To test the api of my web app.

However, the hosts file says:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
```

Is it safe to add the entry I want to add? Can things go wrong?

Comment: Fedora maps the hostname given at install time to `127.0.0.1` under certain circumstances. If I'm not mistaking it happens when you have an Ethernet card, but no network connectivity, e.g. DHCP is not working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "do not change" warning refers to changing the name "localhost".
Many software packages expect "localhost" to resolve to 127.0.0.1.

Adding more entries is not a problem. You can add the entries after the host (as shown by Iain), or add additional lines. For example:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   api.localhost
127.0.0.1   testsite2.localhost
```

On many UNIX-like systems, you can also use `127.0.0.2` and so forth because the whole `127.*.*.*` range is routed to the "local loopback device / driver".

Comment: Quoting from pRFC 5735 - "Special Use IPv4 Addresses"](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5735): *127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host loopback addres*s. So any TCP/IP compliant system including Windows, Linux, MacOSX etc. should route 127.x.y.z addresses to the loopback.

Answer (score 6):

If your hosts file already contains a line for 127.0.0.1 then all you have to do is add your `api.localhost` at the end of it e.g.

```
127.0.0.1               localhost api.localhost
```

Comment: It's perfectly safe, right?

Comment: Yes :-) It's meant to do what you are doing !

Comment: Have a look at the [macos man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/hosts.5.html) for the hosts(5) file which says each line has IP address official hosts name aliases

Answer (score 4):

Yup, this should be safe on any reasonable system. In fact, it's a common ad-blocking technique - for example, you can download premade hosts files filled with the names of common ad servers all pointed at 127.0.0.1.